# XAMPP: Apache wont start Windows Server 2008 Enterprise (php updated to 7.3)

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, php, windows-server-2008, xampp

Xampp was running without any issues on Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I tried to update php from 5 to 7.3 so I downloaded the new version, I copied php.ini file but now apache wont start. It is just stuck on:

> Attempting to start Apache service...

Without any further error logs

Comment: The content of the `php.ini` file has some changes between PHP 5 and 7.3. Put the 7.3 ini file back and then compare the 5 and 7 ini file ONLY make changes to the V7 ini file that you can explain and understand

Comment: I may also be likely that PHP7.3 wont run with the old version of Apache you had.

Comment: Did you also make sure that you had all the new MSVC C/C++ Runtime libraries installed. Also check you have the Universal runtime installed